# How to print every row in ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, frontend

I am going to query data from oracle server. The following is what I get, and i wanna print every row out. But it looks like "<%=%>" only prints the last result, and "<% %>" prints nothing. I am so confused.
I am sure I connect to the oracle server and what I want to print in this case is all 10 country's name.

this my helper.rb file

```
require 'ruby-oci8'
module HomeHelper
    def connect
        oci=OCI8.new('username','password','server/host')
        oci.exec('select name from country fetch first 10 rows only') do |record|
                puts record.join(',')
            end
    end
end
```

this is my html.erb file

```
<%= connect %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In ERB templates, you have two basic ways to execute ruby code.

`<% name %>` (no =) is for embedding **logic**.
`<%= name %>` (with =) is for embedding **values**.

To accomplish what you want, you need a combination of both. Something like this will display them all in your view:

```
<% collection.each do |entry| %>
  <%= entry.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what it's the collection and entry should be? I have no clue.

Comment: `collection` in this case would be an array of something. `entry` is a variable representation of the array value, and `entry.name` would be calling the `name` method on the `entry`. I would read through [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html), because you need to set  `@instance_variables` to expose data to your view as well.

Answer (score 0):

In ERB `puts` and `print` do not actually write to the buffer as you might expect. Consider this example:

```
require 'erb'

def connect
  puts "hello world"
end

template = ERB.new "<% connect %>"
template.result(binding) # "\n"
```

`puts` outputs to standard out. In the context of Rails that means that it would output in the terminal where you're running the server not in the response body that you're sending to the client. If you want to output the buffer in erb you need to use `<%= %>`:

```
require 'erb'

def connect
  "hello world"
end

template = ERB.new "<%= connect %>"
template.result(binding) # "Hello world"
```

If you absolutely must output text within a non-output code block (i.e., <% %>), you can use the [concat method in Rails](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat):

```
require 'ruby-oci8'
module HomeHelper
  def connect
    oci = OCI8.new('username','password','server/host')
    oci.exec('select name from country fetch first 10 rows only') do |record|
     concat record.join(',')
    end
  end
end
```

But this code actually belongs more in a model (or something like a repository class) then a helper in the first place:

```
require 'ruby-oci8'

class Country < Struct.new(:name)
  @oci= OCI8.new('username','password','server/host')

  def self.top_ten
    [].then do |results|
      @oci.exec('select name from country fetch first 10 rows only') do |record|
        results << new(record)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
<%= Country.top_ten.map(&:name).join(', ') %>
```

Comment: first method works, thanks bro. And for the second method, there is an error saying superclass mismatch for class country. Does it mean the "Struct.new(:name)" is not right?